# Проверка на целое число JS

Tags: javascript, проверка

Вступление:
Писал проверку на то что вводит пользователь, реализовывал через input type = 'text', однако потом решил попробовать через prompt и результат один и тот же.

Проблема:
проверял через  Number.isInteger(x);
Если число x введено через input или prompt и далее превращается в целое число parseInt(x). То Number.isInteger(x) покажет false.
Напротив, если число изначально объявить let x = 76, то Number.isInteger(x) - true.

```
n = prompt();
parseInt(n, 10);
console.log(Number.isInteger(n)); //false

n = 67;
console.log(Number.isInteger(n)); //true
```

Вопрос:
Почему так происходит? Как от этого избавиться?

Comment: если угодно, можно еще воспользоваться остатком от деления на 1 `let isInteger = n % 1 === 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Вашей функции Вы задаёте `prompt` переменной n. 
Дальше Вы проводите перевод в число, но не задаёте ей переменную.

Чтобы всё работало - воспользуйтесь:

```js
    n = prompt();
    n = parseInt(n, 10); // Присваиваем переменной n значение перевода в число.
    console.log(Number(n));
    console.log(Number.isInteger(n)); //false

    n = 67;
    console.log(Number(n));
    console.log(Number.isInteger(n)); //true
```

Comment: К сожалению, значения вида `1.23`,`32,32`,`12gfdgdgdf` тоже будут `true`, если использовать ваш код.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko Вопрос это не мой код, вопрос был в том, почему именно в данном случае возвращается false. Додумывание вопроса за автора не приветствуется.

Comment: В коде ТС есть явная ошибка. Также, в нем есть явная логическая ошибка. В шапке вопроса написано - *Проверка на целое число JS*. Т.е. ТС хочет проверить, целое число или нет. Ваш код не проверяет целое это число или нет. Помогать, так уж до конца :)

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде есть ошибка, [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) не изменяет переданное значение, а возвращает новое. В вашем случае при первой проверке `n` является строкой.

Исправленная версия:

```
let n = parseInt(prompt(), 10);
console.log(Number.isInteger(n)); //true

n = 67;
console.log(Number.isInteger(n)); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция `parseInt` пытается распарсить строку в число. Т.е. она довольна не прихотлива и, например значение `23gff` превратит в `23`.

```js
console.log(parseInt('21fgf', 10), Number.isInteger(parseInt('21fgf', 10)));
console.log(parseInt('21.3', 10), Number.isInteger(parseInt('21.3', 10)));
console.log(parseInt('21,32', 10), Number.isInteger(parseInt('21,32', 10)));
console.log(parseInt('21', 10), Number.isInteger(parseInt('21', 10)));
```

Это не то поведение, какое вы ожидаете, как мне кажется.

Что бы этого избежать, надо строку преобразовать в число с помощью `Number`.

```js
console.log(Number('21fgf'), Number.isInteger(Number('21fgf')));
console.log(Number('21.3'), Number.isInteger(Number('21.3')));
console.log(Number('21,32'), Number.isInteger(Number('21,32')));
console.log(Number('21'), Number.isInteger(Number('21')));
```

Comment: На деле можно и не приводить к числу `/^[0-9]+$/.test("5408")`. А с выбора ответов я иногда ~~о...ваю~~.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg в общем-то да. вы правы. Если стоит задача только проверить число ли это, то у регекспов есть несомненные плюсы.